# Add String Array to ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I have 2 `String` Arrays

```
String[] question1 = {"Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"};
String[] question2 = {"Q5","Q6","Q7","Q8"};
```

And one `ArrayList`

```
ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

**How can I manipulate them if i want to access to a member of `ArrayList`.** I tried converting both arrays to String but it doesn't give solution.

Comment: `aList.addAll(Arrays.asList(question1)); aList.addAll(Arrays.asList(question2));`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(question1));
aList.addAll(Arrays.asList(question2));
```

Comment: is it posible to add more arrays in list in the same line of the code, something like  aList.addAll(Arrays.asList(question1,question2,question3...));

Comment: and how i can now to access to some of elements of array

Comment: @GlacialMan *"is it posible to add more arrays in list in the same line of the code"* not really; *"and how i can now to access to some of elements of array"* - `aList.get(0);`, perhaps you should take a closer look at [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Comment: @GlacialMan or maybe take a look at [ArrayList API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: this will get me Array, but i want to access to element of an array, for example i want to work something with q4 element of Array question1.

Comment: `aList.get(idx);` will give you the element at index idx of `aList`. As you know the order you've added your arrays to `aList`, you should know what is the index of your wanted element in `aList`.

Comment: aha ok so if i want to access to Q4 i will do aList.get(3); or if i want to access to Q7 i will do aList.get(6);

Comment: If you refer to your example arrays- you're right :)

Comment: yeah ok that's it thank you :)